# Como habilitar o scrollbar vertical no qwebview em python?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Preciso habilitar o *scrollbar* em um widget `qwebview`, e colocar a rolagem automática, mas não encontrei nenhuma informação a respeito de como fazer isso no python.

Eu tentei fazer assim:

```
self.qwebview.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
```

Mas nao funcionou

Tentei assim:

```
self.qwebview.page().mainFrame().setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
```

Nao funcionou..

Onde que eu uso esse `setVerticalScrollBarPolicy`? E como faço para a barra vertical aparecer?

Comment: Qual código você tem até o momento?

Comment: Na verdade, Paulo, eu crio o webview pelo qtdesign, entao eu ja recebo ele prontinho na minha classe, quando carrego o arquivo .ui
Eu pesquisei um pouco e o comando é algo do tipo:
setVerticalScrollBarPolicy
Mas eu nao consegui aplicar ele na variavel do qwebview

self.qwebview.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
Tipo assim nao funcionou, deve ser algo simples, mas nao estou encontrando um exemplo que funcione

Comment: O [manual](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#setScrollBarPolicy) ajuda nestes casos. Veja se isto resolve: `self.qwebview.page().mainFrame().setScrollBarPolicy( ` **`Qt.Vertical`** `, Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn )` - A função pede dois parâmetros, qual a scrollbar, e qual a política.

Comment: Para completar: `setVerticalScrollBarPolicy` é um método de `QAbstractScrollArea`, e o `QWebFrame` não é descendente de `QAbstractScrollArea`, portanto este método não se aplica. Entretanto, no manual da Qt, linkado acima, o `QWebFrame`  tem o método `setScrollBarPolicy`, que serve para definir se a scrollbar aparece sempre, nunca, ou só quando necessária.

Comment: Consegui usando esse metodo deu certinho, agora falta eu descobrir uma forma de rolar ele ate o fim automaticamente, e minha aplicação estará completa

Comment: @MegaAnim votei para reabrir sua pergunta, se derem mais 4 votos, eu posto melhor formatada como resposta, em vez de comentário. Quanto a rolar para o final, depende muito de como você vai fazer. Se a informação for mudando a toda hora, você pode fazer com JS mesmo. Chamando pela Qt, você pode usar `setScrollBarValue( Qt.Vertical, VALOR )`. Para saber o máximo, tem a propriedade `scrollBarMaximum( Qt.Vertical )`. Uma gambiarra seria por um valor bem alto, que o controle vai capar ele para o tamanho da página, de qualquer forma. Usar o Maximum é mais seguro.

Comment: Eu fiz assim:
self.qwebview.page().mainFrame().setScrollBarValue( Qt.Vertical, self.qwebview.page().mainFrame().scrollBarMaximum( Qt.Vertical ) )
Ta funcionando mais ou menos, mas ele nao vai ate o finalzinho, sempre sobra um pedacinho..
Mas acho que isso acontece por causa do javascript.. O conteudo atualiza constantemente, toda vez que ele atualiza eu chamo call pra um objeto do python dentro do proprio javascript, ai posso chamar funcoes dentro do python, ai chamo a funcao rolagem() com essa funcao dentro..